# How to change the value in controller from directive to fetch new data in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have about five controllers that fetches the data from the server. One of them is the following:

```
var vm = this;


    //vm.paCountSummary.total = ;

    var month = 1;

    loadStatusCount();


    function loadStatusCount() {
        vm.summaryCount = [];

        statusCountService.setMonth(month);
        statusCountService.setType('e');
        statusCountService.getStatusCount()
                    .then(function (report) {
                        applyCount(report);
                    });
    }

    function applyCount(report) {
        vm.summaryCount = report[0];
    }


    vm.getTotal = function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.summaryCount.length; i++) {
            var count = vm.summaryCount[i].count;
            total = total + count;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

the rest of the controller has the same code, but the only difference is the `type`.

Now, I have a directive that displays the template.

```
monthlyReportApp.directive('statusCount', function () {
    return {
        //require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/templates/status-count-template.html',
        link: linker
    }

    function linker(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;
        scope.class = attrs.class;
    }

});
```

And I use it in the HTML like this:

```
<div status-count data-class="fa fa-check-square-o" data-title="Prior Auth Count" class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="PACountCtrl as ctrl">

                </div>
```

It's not really a problem, but I just want to minimize repetition. With that said, if I only want to use a single controller to call the api with different `type` value, how can I do that from the directive? So that different div loads different types of data instead of creating 5-6 different controller that basically does the same thing.

Comment: If I understand well, your question is about the part of code you didn't show?

Comment: why don't you have that code in a service, so you can inject it into your controllers and directive ? Can't you do it more generic to receive the type?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I don't know how to that's why I put the question. Just by looking at it, it seems like the answer that Pankaj Parkar gave is the one that I need. I have to test it before I can select it as an answer. But overall, that's sort of implementation is what I'm looking for. I'm still learning Angular, so there's a lot more I don't know how to do. And passing variables is one of them.

Comment: sorry, at your question wasn't clear for me I thought you knew that services are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `type` from the attribute which you want dynamically. Also you are looking to use this directive multiple times so keep in mind directive should be having isolated scope to make it more reusable component. So I'd recommend you to make you directive to use isolated scope.

Also don't think like assigning controller over DOM using `ng-controller` as you already have directive in a place. You need to basically remove it from the DOM & apply that controller from the directive itself. And then pass that `statusType` from the attribute of directive element. So that you can receive that value from the directive isolated scope, then you could receive that value value inside your directive by doing `scope.statusType` and your actual code of line will look like `statusCountService.setType(scope.statusType);`.

But the problem is as you are using `controllerAs` syntax inside your controller and taking value inside isolated scope, so in that case `scope` doesn't get directly binded with the `this` context of controller. For that we need to use `bindToController` property. Which internally uses `angular.bind` API method & bind all the scope inside the controller `this` context. In angular 1.3 + you will have `bindToController: true` option. But in angular 1.4+ this thing is super easy to do. Instead of having `scope: { /* assign props here */ }` & then use `bindToController: true`, they introduce `bindToController` property to accept object that will be considered as isolated scope as well as those received bindings will mapped to `controller`s this context.

Now its time to look at how could you pass `statusType` to the directive, & there are multiple ways of doing it, I will contrast on some of them which are most widely used. You could assign some `scope` variable inside the controller where directive element belongs like `$scope.statusType = 'e'` and on directive element it would be `status-type="{{statusType}}"`, we have use `@`(one way binding) that's why we need to pass interpolated scope variable inside attribute. Otherwise you could directly just pass `expression` which will evaluated as `string` like `status-type="{{'e'}}"`

Additionally you need to use `bindToController: true` to make the isolated scope values available inside your directive controller context(`this`).

**Markup**

```
<div status-count data-class="fa fa-check-square-o" 
   data-title="Prior Auth Count" 
   class="panel panel-default"
   status-type="{{statusType}}">
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
monthlyReportApp.directive('statusCount', function () {
    return {
        //require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/templates/status-count-template.html',
        link: linker,
        controller: 'PACountCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        //angular 1.3 + code need below to things scope: {}, bindToController
        scope: {
            statusType: "@"
        },
        bindToController: true
        //angular 1.4 + code need only bindToController
        /*
        bindToController: {
           statusType: "@"
        }
        */
    }

    function linker(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;
        scope.class = attrs.class;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand what you're doing, but I'm getting `scope is undefined` error. But if I use `$scope`, it shows `undefined` for the statusType. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm still getting undefined. I have `console.log(vm.statusType);` in my controller that prints `undefined`. And the rest looks exactly like yours.

Comment: @user1828605 which angular version you are using?

Comment: donwloaded from NuGet.. seems like it's v1.4.7. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yup, that worked! This is great!!! Thanks. Now I'm reading your explanation to understand it more clearly. See, I had read about bindToController in the documentation, but it's the nuances that I didn't catch on until just now. Thanks, man! really appreciate it.

Comment: @user1828605 look at my edit in answer..I've corrected my grammar & also added more information why you need `bindToController` over here..& how can you improved that..Tried to cover it by step by step approach

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful.

Comment: @user1828605 Glad to hear that does helped again..Thanks :)